# Data elements not updating correctly (additional elements added not showing + remove not working)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have this d3 file where I have originally 3 circles.
I would like to add a 4th one but the forth one added does not show.
Also, the circles being added cannot be removed for some reason.
Any help please?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    path {
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 0.25px;
      fill: grey;
    }
    </style>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>

    var time = new Date(); 
    var width = 500,
        height = 300;
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([0, 5 ])
        .scale(200)
        .rotate([-180,0]);
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);


    svg.append('svg:image')
          .attr({
            'xlink:href': 'http://cdn.graphicsfactory.com/clip-art/image_files/tn_image/1/1329161-tn_cat-2.jpg',  // can also add svg file here
            x: 50,
            y: 150,
            width: 100,
            height: 100
          });

    svg.append('svg:image')
          .attr({
            'xlink:href': 'http://cdn.graphicsfactory.com/clip-art/image_files/tn_image/1/1329161-tn_cat-2.jpg',  // can also add svg file here
            x: 400,
            y: 150,
            width: 100,
            height: 100
          });


    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);
    var g = svg.append("g"); 

    var jsonCircles = [
      { "name": "1" , "x_axis": 30, "y_axis": 30, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
      { "name": "2" , "x_axis": 70, "y_axis": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple"},
      { "name": "3" , "x_axis": 110, "y_axis": 100, "radius": 20, "color" : "red"}];


    function rand_it(x){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 1);
    };

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };


    function randH(){
      return getRandomInt(150, 250);
    };

    function generate_data(){


        var jsonCircles2 = [
          { "name": "1" , "x_axis": rand_it(width)-10, "y_axis": rand_it(height)-10, "radius": rand_it(20), "color" : "green" },
          { "name": "2" , "x_axis": rand_it(width)-10, "y_axis": rand_it(height)-10, "radius": rand_it(20), "color" : "purple"},
          { "name": "3" , "x_axis": rand_it(width)-10, "y_axis": rand_it(height)-10, "radius": rand_it(20), "color" : "red"},
          { "name": "4" ,"x_axis": rand_it(width)-10, "y_axis": rand_it(height)-10, "radius": rand_it(20), "color" : "blue"}];

          return jsonCircles2;
    };

    var time = new Date(); 
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(jsonCircles, function(d) {
                                            console.log("Here I am: " + time, d );
                                            return d.name;});

    circles.enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
           .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
           .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });




    function move_right(data){
        var timeU = new Date();
        var duration = 1000;
        var delay = 0;

        // join data
        circles.data(data, function(d, i) {
                                        console.log("\n\n Here I am Updated: " + timeU, i, d.name);
                                        return d.name;});


        // Update
        circles
            .transition() // this is to create animations
            .duration(duration)
            // .delay(function(d, i) {delay = i * .5; return delay;}) 
            .ease("linear")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return 500; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return randH(); })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
            // .style('opacity', 0);

        // enter
        circles.enter().append('circle')
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return 150; })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return randH(); })
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
            .style('opacity', 0)
            .transition()
              .duration(duration * 1.2)
              .style('opacity', 1);


        // exit old
        circles.exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration*2)
          .style('opacity', 0)
          .remove();          

    }



    // move_right(jsonCircles)

    setInterval(function(){
      console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

      var data = generate_data();
      move_right(data);
      console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    }, 3000);


    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want the end result to be, but the issue about the fourth circle is because in the move_right function you're joining the data to `circles`, which is the transitional selection from the previous data join.  You should reselect the circles and bind the data to that.  D3 will then figure out what's entering, transitioning, and exiting.

Comment: @RyanLeeSimms, Thanks for the tip. on this.
So do I get this correctly, the flow should be:
enter -> update -> exit
?

Comment: it's not as much about flow as it is that circles, circles.enter() and circles.exit() will all give you different selections.  I think what you want here is to select both the entering and transitioning elements, which would most easily be selected as `svg.selectAll('circle')`.  I know it looks like you already made this selection and set the value to the variable `circles`, but once you bind data to that selection, it behaves differently.